# GNU Screen Caption

Tags: gnu-screen

I have this line in my `.screenrc` file:

```
caption string " %{kw}%-w%{ky}%n-%t%{-}%+w"
```

This is the caption output, where 0 is the active screen:

```
0-bash  1 bash  2 bash
```

How do I customise `%-w` and `%+w` such that it outputs with a dash as well?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change `screen` source code for this, specifically AddWindows function in process.c.